# .htaccess, redirecting /home$ to /, but leaving /home/wp-login alone

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Here are the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /home/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home/index.php [L]

# RewriteRule ^/home$ / [L]
# Redirect 301 /home / <-- this catches /home and /home/, BUT also /home/wp-login.php :/
# Redirect 301 /home$ / <-- doesn't catch /home or /home/, still see error page
```

I'm trying to make `http://example.com/home`, `http://example.com/home/` 301 redirect to `http://example.com`.  What's the magic redirect code to make this happen, where, `/home/{anything-else}` stays put, but, `/home/` and `/home` 301 redirect to `http://example.com`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/home/?$ /
```

But depending on your wordpress setup, the rewrite rules may affect whether this gets redirected or not. You might need to play with the ordering, whether the redirect is before the rewrite rules or after.